# android:how to add more TextView in header of a listview

Tags: android, android-listview

I used AmazinListView to show my list. In header section i want two textview instead of one textview. So I used a linear layout in header instead of textview. But log cat says linear layout cannot convert into textview. How it solve?
below my code :

```
@Override
    protected void bindSectionHeader(View view, int position,
            boolean displaySectionHeader) {
        System.out.println("inside bindSectionHeader");
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    if (displaySectionHeader) {
                        view.findViewById(R.id.header).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                        TextView lSectionTitle = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.header);
                        lSectionTitle.setText(getSections()[getSectionForPosition(position)]);
                } else {
                        view.findViewById(R.id.header).setVisibility(View.GONE);
                }


    }

@Override
    public void configurePinnedHeader(View header, int position, int alpha) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        System.out.println("inside configurePinnedheader");
        TextView lSectionHeader = (TextView)header;
        lSectionHeader.setText(getSections()[getSectionForPosition(position)]);
        lSectionHeader.setBackgroundColor(alpha << 24 | (0xbbffbb));
        lSectionHeader.setTextColor(alpha << 24 | (0x000000));
        /*LinearLayout headerLayout = (LinearLayout)header ;
        headerLayout.setBackgroundColor(alpha << 24 | (0xbbffbb));
        TextView headerTextView = (TextView)header.findViewById(R.id.header);
        headerTextView.setText(getSections()[getSectionForPosition(position)]);*/
    }
```

and my header.xml is:

```
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/header"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
android:background="#bfb"
android:padding="6dp"
android:text="Header"
android:textColor="#000"
android:textStyle="bold" />
```

here i want to use a linear layout instead of text view. so that i can use two textview.

here is my linear layout that i want to use instead of textview

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:padding="6dp"  
android:id="@+id/ll_header1"
android:weightSum="100">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tv_header"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="80"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Header"
    android:textColor="#000"
    android:textStyle="bold" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tv_percent"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="20"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="20%" />
```

Comment: Can you post your code with `LinearLayout` this one is still using textview

Comment: Modify the header.xml to wrap the TextViews with other view and find all the textview by id and set text inside `if (displaySectionHeader)`

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use `LinearLayout` instead of `TextView` in your layout.

In method `configurePinnedHeader()`, you should not just cast `header` to `TextView`.

You can use the code like this:

```
public void configurePinnedHeader(View header, int position, int alpha) {
    TextView tv1 = (TextView)header.findViewById(R.id.your_text_view_id);
}
```

In method `bindSectionHeader`, you should set `LinearLayout` visible or gone, and set set text to TextView.

Comment: if i do it header content appear properly but 1st content of the body of each header does not appear.

Comment: You may get wrong position for header or item. You can check that.